# IE11 keeps asking for credentials on intranet

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication, single-sign-on, windows-authentication

We are creating an intranet site and want to use SSO. The problem is however, that Internet Explorer (11) keeps asking for credentials. By specifying the username and password we are able to access it. Then the intranet application can be used without a problem. When Internet Explorer is closed however it asks for credentials again. The problem occurs on the testing machine (running in a domain) and also on my laptop at home which I also use to develop on. I access the test server with Remote Desktop and then test the site on the same machine as it is running on, which is Windows 2012R2 running IIS 8.5.

On the test server the application (ASP.NET MVC with SignalR and WebAPI) is using a URL that will not be automatically recognized as an intranet site although it is in the same IP range. Therefore I have added the site explicitely to the intranet zone in the settings of IE.

When I then right click on the site and request the properties I can see it is in the intranet zone. This is for as far as I could find the solution in these situations but for us there is something else going on.

This is the system.web section of web.config:

```
<system.web>
  <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.1" />
  <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
  <authentication mode="Windows" />
  <authorization>
    <deny users="?" />
  </authorization>
</system.web>
```

In IIS I have tried enabling both Windows Authentication and Digest and also just one of those. The other authentication options are disabled, including Anonymous Authentication.

I also added the site to the trusted zone which did not help. Also changed the zone settings (for intranet and trusted) to do "Automatic logon on with  the current username and password" but that didn't help either (I don't understand the setting Automatic logon only in Intranet zone though, because it seems a zone specific duplicate setting of the afore mentioned setting but ok). I also checked the advanced settings to be sure that Integrated Windows Security is enabled.

At the moment we're completely out of ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Two more to your checklist:

- make sure you have disabled anonymous authentication
- make sure the domain controller is accessible from both the client PC and the IIS hosting the web app. Chances are the domain controller doesn't recognize the application server as coming from the same domain.

http://www.wiktorzychla.com/2012/06/iis-75-integrated-security-with-no.html

Comment: Is a domain controller required for this, because I have the same problem on my development home laptop which isn't running in a domain.

Anonymous access is also disabled in IIS.

Comment: I doubt the client machine implements the server part of NTLM/Kerberos. I believe domain controller is a must.

Comment: @RonDeijkers Were you able to resolve the issue? I am having the same issue and have not found a solution yet.

Answer (score 0):

I have set the Full control to "Domain Users" in the Security Tab (NTFS permissions) of my Application Folder. Which resolved the problem in IE 11 but chrome is continuously asking for User name and password.